# Using Hibernate Versioning in a middle class of a hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, inheritance, optimistic-locking

I want to use Hibernate Versioning in my application but I have a problem in a class hierarchy like this :
C extends B and B extends A.
I want to use version in Class B and I don’t need to use version in class A and I know when I use versioning in Class B automatically it will be effective in Class C.
I implement inheritance in hibernate with 'joined-subclass' and ‘Version’ tag is not defined for 'joined-subclass'. How can I use versioning in my class hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with joined-subclass, because, as you have already observed, it will apply to any further subclasses.

You'll probably have to use table-per-subclass to get what you want.